# отфильтровать объект json на javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Объект:
   names-array.json

```
[
  {
    "item_1": [
       {
         "value": 2
       },
       {
         "value": 4
       }
    ]
  },
  {
    "item_2": [
       {
         "value": 5
       },
       {
         "value": 6
       }
    ]
  }
]
```

Нужно вытащить:

```
[
   {
     "value": 5
   },
   {
     "value": 6
   }
]
```

Попытка решения (node.js)

```
const namesArray = require('./names-array.json');

function findAvailable(name) {

  return namesArray.filter(item => {
    return item.hasOwnProperty(name);
  });
}
```

Да, filter создал опять массив и его можно убрать добавив [0], но останется item_2, и это какое-то корявое решение.

```
console.log(findAvailable('item_2')[0])
```

Результат:

```
{ 
  item_2: [ 
    { 
      value: 5
    }, 
    { 
      value: 6
    } 
  ]
}
```

Как получить желаемое?

Comment: А какой у вас желаемый результат?

Comment: В разделе "Нужно вытащить:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, по какому правилу надо фильтровать, но давайте условимся: у нас есть ключ и нам нужно получить, все значение объекта, у которого есть этот ключ

```js
const data = [
  {
    "item_1": [
       {
         "value": 2
       },
       {
         "value": 4
       }
    ]
  },
  {
    "item_2": [
       {
         "value": 5
       },
       {
         "value": 6
       }
    ]
  }
];


const getFilteredData = (key, data) => {
  const result = data.find(e => e.hasOwnProperty(key));
  
  if (!result) return undefined;
  
  return result[key];
}
console.log(getFilteredData('item_1', data));
console.log(getFilteredData('item_2', data));
console.log(getFilteredData('never', data));
```

Немного про [метод](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) `find`

> Метод find() возвращает значение первого найденного в массиве элемента, которое удовлетворяет условию переданному в callback функции.  В противном случае возвращается undefined.

#### Note

Если в массиве будет несколько элементов, где есть нужный ключ, вернется самый первый. В условиях это не сказано, поэтому подразумевал, что всегда есть только один объект. Но и реализовать вариант с множеством будет не сложно

Comment: Мне кажется, что выкидывать эксепшен, если ничего не нашлось - не самая мудрая идея...

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko заменил на `undefined`